# Time Indicator animation in IOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, timer

I am working on a quiz application where , every question have different Time period .
I wants to implement an animation where **circumference of circle** should be decrease as time is over & at the end of time it will be lost . [as shown in image here](http://s1313.photobucket.com/user/anupamiise/media/rsz_multiplechoice_zps13c46720.png.html?filters%5Buser%5D=139708366&filters%5Brecent%5D=1&sort=1&o=0)

Same behaviour I want in every question .
Please help me ,if nay one have any confusion please let me know.

Comment: You can load an image on another site such as http://photobucket.com and then put a link here.  Cocoacontrols.com is also a good source of UI elements - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=timer

Comment: the link of image is  http://s1313.photobucket.com/user/anupamiise/media/rsz_multiplechoice_zps13c46720.png.html?filters[user]=139708366&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/circulartimer) or [this one](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kkprogresstimer)
It is also worth finding out about [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org), although the first control doesn't have a Pod yet.

To use these controls you can just add a UIView in IB and then set the custom class of the UIView to the control (such as kkprogresstimer).

Answer (score 0):

**testView** is a UIView class which draws the Circle. Initializing this in a UIViewController class.

```
self.testView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 700.0)];
self.testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.testView];
```

**timeLabel** is the label which shows the remaining time.

```
self.timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195.0, 195.0, 20.0, 12.0)];
[self.timeLabel setText:@"10"];
self.timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.timeLabel];
```

aTimer is a NSTimer variable which calls the myAnimate method every 2 seconds.

NSTimer *aTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(myAnimate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

myAnimate method reduces the circumference of the circle and also the value of the timeLabel.

```
- (void)myAnimate {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        if (self.testView.aFloat >= 36) {
            int a = [self.timeLabel.text  intValue];
            self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", a -1];
            self.testView.aFloat = self.testView.aFloat - 36;
            [self.testView setNeedsDisplay];
        }
    } completion:nil];
}
```

UITestView draws the circle.

UITestView.h

```
@interface TestView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat aFloat;
- (void)myAnimate;

@end
```

UITestView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    CGContextAddArc(context, 200.0, 200.0, 75.0, 0, [self DegreesToRadians:_aFloat], 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

- (CGFloat)DegreesToRadians:(CGFloat)degrees {
    return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}
```

Hope, this was of some assistance.